# How to build a Ruby hash out of two equally-sized arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have two arrays

```
a = [:foo, :bar, :baz, :bof]
```

and

```
b = ["hello", "world", 1, 2]
```

I want

```
{:foo => "hello", :bar => "world", :baz => 1, :bof => 2}
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

```
h = Hash[a.zip b] # => {:baz=>1, :bof=>2, :bar=>"world", :foo=>"hello"}
```

...damn, I love Ruby.

Comment: It's pretty obvious but if anyone is wondering, if you want to get the original arrays from the new hash you can just call `h.keys` and `h.values`.

Answer (score 45):

Just wanted to point out that there's a slightly cleaner way of doing this:

```
h = a.zip(b).to_h # => {:foo=>"hello", :bar=>"world", :baz=>1, :bof=>2}
```

Have to agree on the "I love Ruby" part though!

Answer (score 17):

How about this one?

```
[a, b].transpose.to_h
```

If you use Ruby 1.9:

```
Hash[ [a, b].transpose ]
```

I feel `a.zip(b)` looks like `a` is master and `b` is slave, but in this style they are flat.

Answer (score 1):

Just for curiosity's sake:

```
require 'fruity'

a = [:foo, :bar, :baz, :bof]
b = ["hello", "world", 1, 2]

compare do
  jtbandes { h = Hash[a.zip b] }
  lethjakman { h = a.zip(b).to_h }
  junichi_ito1 { [a, b].transpose.to_h }
  junichi_ito2 { Hash[ [a, b].transpose ] } 
end

# >> Running each test 8192 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> lethjakman is similar to junichi_ito1
# >> junichi_ito1 is similar to jtbandes
# >> jtbandes is similar to junichi_ito2

compare do 
  junichi_ito1 { [a, b].transpose.to_h }
  junichi_ito2 { Hash[ [a, b].transpose ] } 
end

# >> Running each test 8192 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> junichi_ito1 is faster than junichi_ito2 by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
```