# Create a hash using two arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, merge

I need to create a new Hash object using two arrays.

But, the conditions is first array value should be a key value for the Hash and second array value should be the Hash value.

```
a = ["x", "y"] 
b = [2, 4]
```

Result should be: `c = {"x" => 2, "y" => 4}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build a Ruby hash out of two equally-sized arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359659/how-to-build-a-ruby-hash-out-of-two-equally-sized-arrays)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> a = ["x", "y"]; b = [2, 4]
=> [2, 4]
irb(main):002:0> Hash[a.zip(b)]
=> {"x"=>2, "y"=>4}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm just joking.. "Ruby" have the answers for all the Questions. ;)