# Turn key/value pairs into hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine two Arrays into Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174913/combine-two-arrays-into-hash)

I have an model which stores key value pairs as attributes for another model person.

What is a simple way of turning person.person_attributes into a hash?

This is a stupid way I came up with:

```
keys = person.person_attributes.map(&:key)
values = person.person_attributes.map(&:value)

hashed_attributes = Hash.new

keys.each_index do |i|
  hashes_attribues[keys[i]] = values[i]
end
```

What is a more elegant way to do this?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine two Arrays into Hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174913/combine-two-arrays-into-hash) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359659/how-to-build-a-ruby-hash-out-of-two-equally-sized-arrays

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate - my understanding is that there is only one array (`person_attributes`) and we need to build a hash from methods called on the items in that array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) for these sort of things

```
attributes = person.person_attributes.each_with_object({}) do |attribute, hash|
  hash[attribute.key] = attribute.value
end
```

If you're still on Ruby 1.8.7, not to worry, [Rails has backported this method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

Answer (score 2):

You want to turn an array of objects, each with a `key` and `value` property, into a hash where the `key` maps to the `value`?

You can use the following, which uses `Hash[array]` to turn a two-dimensional array into a hash:

```
Hash[person.person_attributes.map { |e| [e.key, e.value] }]
```

#### Input:

```
Obj = Struct.new(:key, :value)

[ { Obj.new(:key1, :value1) },
  { Obj.new(:key2, :value2) },
  { Obj.new(:key3, :value3) }
]
```

#### Output:

```
{ :key1 => :value1, :key2 => :value2, :key3 => :value3 }
```

Comment: judging by the OP code, items are not hashes.